# Last user's name/answer on question

Tags: support

Sometimes an answer is deleted and it just happens that it's the last answer for that question, thus being displayed under the respective question on the main page (see the picture below) ([this is the question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/419/facebook-share-link-feature-feature-for-blogger-google-buzz-or-other-blogs)).
If that particular answer was deleted, shouldn't the user below the question be updated to the one that posted the last valid one? For instance, *NOD32 Offline Update*'s answer for the above mentioned question was deleted, so the latest valid answer is the one of *Matt Katz*. Shouldn't he be the one appearing? I find it somehow misleading the way it is now.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been raised on Meta Stack Overflow before:

[Last activity might refer to author of deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72992/last-activity-might-refer-to-author-of-deleted-answer)

[Incorrect last activity user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75828/incorrect-last-activity-user)

[When an answer is deleted change person listed as last modifier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70024/when-an-answer-is-deleted-change-person-listed-as-last-modifier)

None of which have been addressed over there fully.

Comment: The way I see it, it's a bug. But it seems to be considered a feature - if you have a >10k reputation, you can see the respective answers.